# How to add White Balance to Camera

Tags: android

I am developing my application on Note 9.
If i open normal camera, i can see white balance, contrast, brightness etc features and panoramic shot.

But if i open my developed application, i cant see these features. There is only flashlight, camera, video.

> So how can i add these features on my application if the user's phone has?

```
/**
     * Capturing Camera Image will launch camera app requested image capture
     */
 private void captureImage() {
       Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        File file = CameraUtils.getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (file != null) {
            imageStoragePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        }

        Uri fileUri = CameraUtils.getOutputMediaFileUri(getApplicationContext(), file);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
  }
```

And my `manifest`:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

the "normal camera" is actually an application where they implement several features, this is why the features might vary alot between phones.

if you want those features on your camera you need to implement them. perhaps this can help:

- [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251120/how-should-i-set-exposure-and-white-balance-values-for-custom-camera)
- [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters)